# Checking a string is palindromic using stacks

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I want to check a string is palindromic using stacks implement in java. I have tried many ways but its not getting me the correct answer. Can someone help me with it?

I have implemented a Stack in my class which variable name is "stackArray".

Palindromic method :

```
Stack s1 = new Stack(5);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    s1.push(stackArray[i]);
}

String [] reverser = new String[5];

while (!s1.isEmpty()) {
    int count = 0;
    reverser[count] = s1.pop();
    count++;
}

if (s1.equals(reverser)){
    System.out.println("The input String is a palindrome.");
}
else
    System.out.println("The input String is not a palindrome.");
```

Driver code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 

        Stack st = new Stack(5);

        st.push("l");
        st.push("e");
        st.push("v");
        st.push("e");
        st.push("l");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("When Palindromic is starting; ");
        System.out.println("");
        st.palindromic();
}
```

Its obvious that the word "level" is Palindromic but always it says "The input String is not a palindrome."

Comment: Your code is incomplete -- the Stack implementation is missing.
Please provide minimal code showing your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'd create a separate class that receives the input string in the constructor.  That class should have a method called `IsPalindromic()` that returns true/false.  Inside this class you'd use your Stack class.  This class could internally have a `Reversed()` function that simply pushes all letters onto the internal stack, and then returns a new string with the values concatenated as you pop them back off.  Then `IsPalindromic()` could just compare the original passed in string with the reversed string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two fundamental problems with your solution:

1. You are popping s1 until it is empty and then doing your palindrome check
2. s1 and reverser are not the same data type

1) Ignoring bullet 2 for the time being, it looks like s1 is empty when you use it to determine if the input is a palindrome. You'll need to make sure that when you do an equivalence check both the variables point to structures with data in them!

2) s1 is a Stack and reverser is a String[]. The default implementation of 'equals' in Stack is to check if the argument is an instance of a Stack. Since this will never be the case, you will always see "The input String is not a palindrome.".

To fix 2), you'll need to make both objects the same data type (either both Stack or String[]). If you choose the latter String[], you will need to verify that the Strings at each index i are equivalent in both s1 and reverser.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment.                                                                   
But when it comes to 2) I created stack which the variable type is String which is implemented in form of an array. That's why i created String reverser with the array data structure as well. Can you suggest me a function which checks the element of both arrays?

Comment: @Manodhya Ah I see. If both your stackArray and reverser are of type String[] and reverser is truly the reverse of stackArray, then you should be able to simply call Arrays.equals(stackArray, reverser).

Comment: @Manodhya if this did the trick, would you mind officially accepting the answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check the implementation of the equals method in your stack class, since the implementation is not posted is hard to find the problem. But instead if you don't need to do it you can do the comparison in the same method. Remember to use the same data type. For example cast the array and the stack to a string. Then use the equals method of the string class.

```
String original = "level"; //The contents of you stack dumped into a String
String[] reversedArr = {"l", "e", "v", "e", "l"}; //And your array reverser

String reversed = "";

for (String letter : reversedArr)
    reversed = reversed.concat(letter);

System.out.println(original.equals(reversed));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer                                                                     But i think i did the same thing you did manually. I pushed characters of "level" to a stack which the variable type is String and implemented in the form of array and poped those values to a another String array (String reverser). Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @ManodhyaOpallage, In your if statement "s1.equals(reverser)", "s1" type is stack and "reverser" is a String[]. Every equals method should return false in that comparison. The idea of my post was to show that you could form 2 strings out of the String arrays in your code (reverser and stackArray) and use them to make the comparison without using the equals method in the Stack class.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much and much more merits :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm re-learning Java after not using it for two decades.  Here's an implementation of my previous comment on your main post.  My stack is OOP based instead of using an internal array:

```
public class Palindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        java.util.Scanner keyboard = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the word to check: ");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        Palindrome p = new Palindrome(input);
        System.out.println("Input: " + p.getInput());
        System.out.println("Reversed: " + p.getInputReversed());
        System.out.println("Palindromic: " + p.isPalindromic());
    }

    private String _input;

    public Palindrome(String input)
    {
        _input = input.toLowerCase();
    }

    public String getInput()
    {
        return _input;
    }

    public String getInputReversed()
    {
        CharStack chars = new CharStack(getInput());    
        String reversed = "";
        while(!chars.empty())
        {
            try {
                reversed = reversed + chars.pop();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return reversed;
    }

    public boolean isPalindromic()
    {
        return getInput().equals(getInputReversed());
    }

    private class CharStack
    {

        private CharStackNode top = null;

        private class CharStackNode
        {
            public char c;
            public CharStackNode next = null;

            public CharStackNode(char inC, CharStackNode top)
            {
                c = inC;
                next = top;
            }
        }

        public CharStack(String input)
        {
            for(char c: input.toCharArray())
            {
                push(c);
            }
        }

        public void push(char c)
        {
            top = new CharStackNode(c, top);;
        }

        public char pop() throws Exception
        {
            if (!empty())
            {
                char c = top.c;
                top = top.next;
                return c;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot pop() an empty stack!");
            }
        }

        public boolean empty()
        {
            return top == null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance. I understand and much more merits for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

    String str ="word";
    if(str.equals(reverse(str))) {
          System.out.println("Word is Palindromic ");
    }else {
          System.out.println("Word is Not Palindromic ");
    }
}


public static String reverse(String str) {
    char[] charArr = str.toCharArray();
    int size = charArr.length;
    Stack stack = new Stack(size);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        stack.push(charArr[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        charArr[i] = stack.pop();
    }

    return String.valueOf(charArr);
}
```

Comment: You must not compare strings in Java using `==` (unless you really know what you are doing)

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderPavlov . Is it ok if i use equals()

Comment: Yes. Though, I  do not think building of reverse string is necessary. You can return stack, pop elements one by one and compare characters with original string